# Create Heroku pipelines with different build command

Tags: heroku

I have a repo with 2 different build/start commands: one for the app itself, and another to run Storybook. Yes, I know Storybook should be on its own repo but for now we have everything in a single repo.

How can I build 2 pipelines, one that starts with `npm build` and `npm start`, and another pipeline that uses `npm run build-storybook` and `npm run storybook`?

I can't use a Procfile since they are both on the main branch.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on this exact issue. Unfortunately I was unable to find a solution because Heroku automatically runs the [build command on deployment](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1557).

I pivoted to using [Chromatic](https://www.chromatic.com/docs/cli) because it has built in Storybook deployments.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).